# Array manipulation in python

Tags: python, arrays

Let's suppose I have this simple array:

```
simple_list = [    
    ('1', 'a', 'aa'),    
    ('2', 'b', 'bb'),    
    ('3', 'c', 'cc')
]
```

If we consider this list as a table, where columns are separated by comas and lines separated by tuples, I want to create a function that retrieves only the columns I want. for example, this function would look like something like this:

```
get_columns(array, tuple_columns_selector))
```

I want, for example, to collect only the first and third column out of it, in this case, it would return me another array with the new values:

if I do:

```
get_columns(simple_list, (0,2))     
get_columns(simple_list, (0,))
```

it will return something like:

```
[('1', 'aa'), ('2', 'bb'), ('1', 'cc')]    
[1, 2, 3]
```

And so on. Could you help me creating this get_columns function, please? Here's the code I've tried:

```
def get_columns(arr, columns): 
    result_list = [] 
    for ii in arr: 
        for i in columns: 
            result_list.append(ii[i]) 
    return result_list 


to_do_list = [
    ('Wake Up', True), 
    ('Brush Teeh', True), 
    ('Go to work', True), 
    ('Take a shower', True), 
    ('Go to bed', False) 
] 

print(get_columns(to_do_list, (0,)))
```

Comment: I show you my code if you show me yours :-) Even if its incorrect, just show what you've tried. We can help you fix it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include details of what you have tried, specifically, show us some code that you may have tried to write.

Comment: These are not arrays. But actually, this sounds like a great use-case *for actual arrays*, specifically, structured `numpy.array`s

Comment: Shouldn't `get_columns(simple_list, (0,))` return `[('1'), ('2'), ('3')]`? Since it should return a list of tuples...

Comment: OP, it might be worth using a pandas dataframe.  This sort of operation has built-in support if you're using data frames.  It's quite a rabbit hole but totally worth it, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

> Use the magic of [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and `map`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

simple_list = [
    ('1', 'a', 'aa'),
    ('2', 'b', 'bb'),
    ('3', 'c', 'cc')
]

cols = (1,) # can be (0, 2)
fn = itemgetter(*cols)
print map(fn, simple_list)
```

Returns:

```
[('1', 'aa'), ('2', 'bb'), ('3', 'cc')]
```

when `cols` is `(0, 2)`.

And it returns:

```
[1,2,3]
```

when `cols` is `(1,)`.

So your get_columns function can be

```
def get_columns(data, cols):
    return map(itemgetter(*cols), data)
```

Comment: Ah, very nice solution, much better than what I was originally thinking of. This handles the OP's logic of getting single elements or a tuple of elements very elegantly.

Comment: Cheers, I'm new to programming, I am not very familiarized to modules but that's a very interesting way of solving it. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @kopos looks fine, I just wanted to share one without additional libraries.

```
simple_list = [
    ('1', 'a', 'aa'),
    ('2', 'b', 'bb'),
    ('3', 'c', 'cc')
]

def get_columns(array, tuple_columns_selector):
    return [tuple(elem[i] for i in tuple_columns_selector) for elem in array]

def get_columns_multiple_lines(array, tuple_columns_selector):
    # The only difference between the result of this version and the other is that this one returns a list of lists
    # while the other returns a list of tuples
    resulting_list = []  # Create the variable that will store the resulting list
    for elem in array:  # Loop for each element in array
        resulting_list.append([])  # We add a new "empty row" to store all the columns needed
        for i in tuple_columns_selector:  # Loop for each column needed
            resulting_list[-1].append(elem[i])  # We append the column value to the last item in resulting_list
    return resulting_list


print get_columns(simple_list, (0,2))  # outputs [('1', 'aa'), ('2', 'bb'), ('3', 'cc')]
print get_columns(simple_list, (0,))  # outputs [('1',), ('2',), ('3',)]
print get_columns_multiple_lines(simple_list, (0,2))  # outputs [['1', 'aa'], ['2', 'bb'], ['3', 'cc']]
```

The only difference is the return value when tuple_columns_selector is only one column. If it's an important difference, I can "correct" it, but you should think about how that value will be used and if it's convenient for it to have different possible structures.

Comment: Thanks a mil, you've done exactly what I wanted. It's a bit confusing for me this one lined for though. I've not yet got used to it but I will, for sure. Nah, no need to change the (1,) to 1. It's fine.

Comment: I added a more simple, not one-line approach.